# Pandas apply combined with shift

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, forex

I am trying to find the relative movement of a currency for each time interval.

I have a table like this:

```
Date        USD_NOK EUR_USD EUR_NOK  
2020-08-09  9.03267 1.17732 10.60526 
2020-08-10  8.97862 1.17749 10.58188
```

And a function like this:

```
def RelativeStrength(table):
    f1 = table.iloc[0][2]
    f2 = table.iloc[0][0]
    t1 = table.iloc[1][2]
    t2 = table.iloc[1][0]
    n = pow(((f1*f2)/(t1*t2)),1/3)
    n1 = t1 * (n/f1)
    n2 = t2 * (n/f2)
    return n, n1, n2
```

However, the tables contain decades of data with a lot shorter intervals than per day, and I have a lot of these.

The function needs to be run on each row, where the row is to be compared to the row before.

I could easily complete this by a for-loop, but that would probably take days with the datasets I have. Hence, I hope to use apply or something similar.

I have tried something like this:

```
table.apply(lambda x: [x[0].shift()], axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

And hoping to get a result looking like this, which I do not:

```
Date        USD_NOK EUR_USD EUR_NOK  NOK    USD    EUR
2020-08-09  9.03267 1.17732 10.60526 1.0021 0.0876 0.9923
2020-08-10  8.97862 1.17749 10.58188 1.0027 1.0005 0.9967
```

(The results for 2020-08-09 are made up, as they are dependent on the fx-crosses for 2020-08-08, which I have not posted)

However, it seems like apply only looks at one line at a time. Is it possible to use apply to make calculations on each row, including considering the row before?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I would like to get three new columns in my data frame for the three values

Comment: Please post the expected output in the question not in comments.

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202110/pandas-apply-function-to-multiple-columns-and-multiple-rows

Comment: see `rolling.apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your operations (`*`, `/` and `**`) has built-in vectorized support by default, I'd suggest you to do the calculation directly without `.apply()`.

```
df["f1_t1"] = df["EUR_NOK"].shift() / df["EUR_NOK"]  # f1 over t1
df["f2_t2"] = df["USD_NOK"].shift() / df["USD_NOK"]  # f2 over t2
df["NOK"] = (df["f1_t1"] * df["f2_t2"])**(1/3)
df["USD"] = df["NOK"] / df["f1_t1"]
df["EUR"] = df["NOK"] / df["f2_t2"]

# output
df
         Date  USD_NOK  EUR_USD  ...       NOK       USD       EUR
0  2020-08-09  9.03267  1.17732  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  2020-08-10  8.97862  1.17749  ...  1.002740  1.000529  0.996740
```

Note that intermediate variables that can be **reused multiple times** are created instead of simple shift. This part is specific to your formula. The number of operations can thus be further reduced.